# how to remove checked items/ specific items from an array list / listview

Tags: android, arrays, listview, arraylist, android-listview

I have this code i am used to pass an array list to another page and show it as a listview. When the list shows up, i want to be able to check an item and remove it at "button click" which will modify the array.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.oppout);

    final ListView lv2 = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.custom_list_view);
    lv2.setClickable(true);
    lv2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Oppout.this, 
                                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked,
                                            Entername.playerList));

    lv2.setOnItemClickListener (
        new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView,
                                    View view,int arg2, long arg3) {
                int selectedPosition = adapterView.getSelectedItemPosition();                                 
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "mu"+ selectedPosition,  
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                               
            }
    });


    Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // on click call the adapterview and delete string at selected position.
            // This is my problem, am not getting how to call the adapter and deleted
            // the selected item/position
            int selectedPosition = adapterView.getSelectedItemPosition();
            adapterView.remove(player.SelectedPosition);

            Intent myIntent = new Intent (view.getContext(), Callacab.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
    });
}}
```

Comment: I updated formatting and indentation on the last method.

Comment: Click on the "edit" link below the tag buttons and you'll see the diff.

Comment: ok u reformatted my code..thanks

Comment: does any one have a real solution not just reformatting my code..but a solution to my real problem..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

contacts.remove(index); //the arraylist you gave it to your adapter

arrayadapter.remove(index);  // this is your adapter that you give it to the listview
  arrayadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

//you can delete from your arraylist or your adapter and then notifyDataSetChanged(); to make the effect happen in your listview....it better to delete from arraylist and its indexs will be the arg2 in your listview item listener